# "Conflicting versions" error while running eggdrop

Tags: http

I'm getting this error while running the [eggdrop bot](http://www.eggheads.org/), while loading the `http.tcl` script:

> conflicting versions provided for package "http": 2.7.5, then 2.5.2

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you provide some output showing the problem?

Comment: More context like OS, and a link to this eggdrop thing would be helpful too. And some information about package `http` as well, since that is referenced in the error message.

Comment: what is your $auto_path, and show us the command you use to load http.tcl (load, package require, ?)

Comment: isn't eggdrop a technology used in chat clients to launch various malware, etc (It probably also has a positive use. Maybe 'meeeeeee' can enlighten us.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the command "package provide http X.Y.Z" is executed twice, but with different version numbers. Have a look in your pkgindex.tcl and fix the version numbers.